# Android: Actionbarsherlock has not been added as a library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

To Make **Tab Actionbar**, I have added the *actionbarsherlock.jar*. ([I have Downloaded it from here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples))

Unfortunately  With (Right click -> Prpperties -> Java Build Path ), it does not placed in **Android Dependency** but in the **Android Private Libreray**.

Now the problem is in:

`public class TabNavigationCollapsed extends TabNavigation`

the Eclipse does not know the **TabNavigation class**

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the whole ABS project into your Eclipse, then in your Project you would add the ABS project as a library under the Android category of your project's preferences.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Comment: I just thought that the purpose of ABS  is to showing the whole abilities of sherlock so i just need the Tab Navigation featurs and not all of them

Comment: You can't do that, you must import the whole project.

Comment: Ok and do u think is there any other way except using this project?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it as `existing Android-Project into your Workspace. (NOT as .jar-file)`
after you added it. you should right-Click on your project -> "Properties "-> "Android" -> click onto "Add..." -> choose the Folder of ActionBarSherlock

After you did this. Right click on actionbarsherlock project -> Properties -> Android -> check the Box "Is Library" -> Apply and Close. (Should be working now)

Comment: Ok and do u think is there any other way except using this project?

Comment: hm, i dont think so. But what is bad about importing the whole Project, you can use everything aswell?

Comment: I think it makes my project a little heavy. isn't it?
And more over i have always thought using nested project is unprofessional. If u can create the library  project why don't u create that in the second one?

Comment: In my opinion it's totally okay to add the whole project folder. It doesnt make your project more unprofessional or heavier at all. Its the same with for example the google_play_service which is a whole project folder too. You won't use everything from that project but everybody does it like this :)

Comment: It can't be added as a simple JAR file because the project needs to include the original resources as well. So the only way is to do it as a library project.